# Remote Config implemented at rnfirebase have a mandatory subscription?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, react-native-firebase

Initially I implemented the exactly Remote Config example from that link:

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/config/example

```
    firebase.config().fetch()
  .then(() => {
    return firebase.config().activateFetched();
  })
  .then((activated) => {
    if (!activated) console.log('Fetched data not activated');
    return firebase.config().getValue('hasExperimentalFeature');
  })
  .then((snapshot) => {
    const hasExperimentalFeature = snapshot.val();

    if(hasExperimentalFeature) {
      enableSuperCoolFeature();
    }

    // continue booting app
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

My idea is not subscribe the Remote Config. I just would like to know if it have any changes at APP startup (componentWillMount).

But I see that using that code above the Remote Config variables are not updating at a new APP startup. I searched and found that info about 12 hours cache:

> Remote Config caches values locally after the first successful fetch
>   request. By default the cache expires after 12 hours, but you can
>   change the cache expiration for a specific request by passing the
>   desired cache expiration, in seconds, to
>   fetchWithExpirationDuration:completionHandler: (on iOS) or fetch (on
>   Android).

They also NOT recommend to change that cache to a small value:

> Note that if you reduce this expiration time to a very small value,
>   you might start hitting the client-side throttling limit, which
>   prevents your client from making a fetch request more than a few times
>   per hour.

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#remote-config-requests

**BUT**, as I have to update values at APP startup, I decided to not follow this recommendation and test. In my tests using `firebase.config().fetch(0)`**(fetch 0 to avoid cache)** the APP apparentely is not subscribing the Remote Config. There are no listeners at javascript side.

So, could I continue using `firebase.config().fetch(0)` without worry? The update only occurs when code runs?
How is the internal implementation of `firebase.config().fetch() / snapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

Using cache timeout of 0 seconds is only meant for development purposes. This will not work for you in production.

As per the documentation, you can fetch 5 times in a 60 minute window - before getting throttled by the client SDK.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Firebase documentation right? But here we have a RNFirebase API in front of Firebase SDK. So, how it is implemented at RNFirebase side? Apparently RNFirebase is not doing any kind of pooling even if timeout is set as 0. Is only get data at app restart.